# Cannot Acessing Array Outside Closure Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, facebook

I have this closure which I use to populate my array and dictionary. However, when I try to use it outside the function, it's empty. Here's my code:

```
var pages: [FBPages] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Facebook.getUserInfo(greetingLabel: greetingLabel, profileImage: profilePic)

    pages = []

    let params = ["fields": "about,name,created_time,picture", "limit": "3"]
    Facebook.getUserPagesLikes(params: params, handler: { (userData) in

        guard let pagesArrays = userData["data"] as? Array<Any> else {return}

        for dict in pagesArrays {

            let fbPages = FBPages()
            let pagesData = dict as! NSDictionary
            fbPages.about = pagesData["about"] as! String
            fbPages.name = pagesData["name"] as! String
            self.pages.append(fbPages)

        }


        print("pages array: \(pagesArrays)")
        print("pages : \(self.pages.count)")



    }) { (error) in
        print("cannot get FB pages: \(String(describing: error))")
    }




    //I got 0 here
    print("fb array: \(pages.count)")

}
```

I tried to print array count outside closure but I only got 0 as a result. How can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is 0 because getUserPagesLikes is not yet complete before you print.

Comment: yes i know, so how can I fix this code so that I can access array outside closure?

Comment: load your tableview/collectionview/or whatever logic in the closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to understand that the time you are printing array. It is not yet available. `getUserPagesLikes` is an async call. Which is taking a completion handler. Once the response comes back, you will have values in your array.

You can understand the sequence like you ask `getUserPagesLikes` to fetch the user likes for you and you don't wait for user likes there. You move ahead, and whatever code you write after completion block gets called. Which in your case turns out to be printing array.

Once the `getUserPagesLikes` gets back the data for you its completion block gets called. At this time you assign the array values. The values in array would be available after this only. So if you want to reload data in table view do it in completion handler. Also make sure that you do it on main thread.

For a detail information on completion handler and their sequence of call you can go through [here](https://swiftwithsadiq.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/completion-handler-in-swift/).

Comment: thank you for your great explanation, finally i'm able to solve this by adding **tableview.reloadData()** at the end of closure, now my tableView working as planned.